# Laravel. Eloquent query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I got this query:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->whereExists(function($query)
        {
            $query->select(DB::raw(1))
               ->from('galleries')
               ->whereRaw('galleries.user_id = users.id');
        })->get();
```

This query selects all users who have gallery. Problem is that I can't use eloquent releationships now. Whenever i try to loop like this:

```
@foreach ($user->gallery as $gallery)
    {{$gallery->name}}      
@endforeach
```

I get error:

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$gallery
```

It happens with all other tables. What am I doing wrong here? My realationships are defined and they work just fine, i got problems only in this query. Thanks.

**EDIT**
Since it's not eloquent query, could you show me example how to write query, into few tables with eloquent. For example, I need all **users** who have their status **approved**  in **example** table

Comment: You're not selecting from the `User` model, you're selecting from `DB::table('users')`.

Comment: You're not using eloquent here, you're using fluent, 2 different things. If `users` and `galeries` are in a relation, you shouldn't need to do this to being with.

Comment: Thanks. So could you show me an example how do i write eloquent query for 2 tables? Since I need only those users, who have gallery? It's just example, in real time project I have to pick all users, where galleries have status approved.

Comment: post your User and Gallery model code please

Comment: I manage to do it by myself. I used User:: instead of DB::table('users'). Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, determine a relationship in the User class, like this:

```
class User {
    // Determine relation to Example table
    public function examples() {
        return $this->hasMany('Example', 'user_id', 'id'); // second parameter is the foreign key
    }
}
```

Then the query:

```
User::whereHas('examples', function( $query ) {
    $query->where('status','approved');
})->get();
```